# Unable to find Bind() on OptionsBuilder

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-7.0

I have a class library that was written in .NET 5 and used the Microsoft.AspNetCore package, which is now deprecated.  After upgrading my library to .NET 7 I'm getting this error:

> 'OptionsBuilder<AamSettings>' does not contain a definition for 'Bind' and no accessible extension method 'Bind' accepting a first argument of type 'OptionsBuilder<AamSettings>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I look at the [OptionsBuilderExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsbuilderconfigurationextensions.bind?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) docs I see an extension method for Bind listed as being part of the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection namespace.  My library includes that NuGet package, and the file has a `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` line at the top of the file.

What am I missing in order to be able to call `Bind`?

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddAamClient(this IServiceCollection services, AamClientRegistrationOptions options)
{
    services
        .AddOptions<AamSettings>()
        .Bind(options.Configuration.GetRequiredSection(options.ConfigurationSectionName))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` you could use:

```
services
    .AddOptions<AamSettings>()
    .BindConfiguration(options.ConfigurationSectionName);
```